# Enumerate items in an XSLT node list

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have some xml like this:

```
<people>
    <person id="7" name="Arthur">
    <person id="82" name="Lancelot">
    <person id="14" name="Guinevere">
</people>
```

In my XSLT, in a context *where I am **not** iterating through this nodeset*, I want to be able to determine the position of the node with a given id within the `<people>` tag.

So, for example, I have an `id` of `82`.  I want to be able to output `2`, because Lancelot, with id `82`, is the second item in the list.

Constraints:

- I am limited to XSLT 1.0
- I am limited to a single XSLT transformation.  So I cannot simply transform the XML above by adding a `position` attribute and then run an additional transform to get my result.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="idToCheck" select="'82'" />
<xsl:variable name="positionOfPerson" select="/people/person[*work-your-magic-here*]" />
```

The XSLT doesn't need to look exactly like that.  If there is a solution using `<xsl:key>` or requiring a loop within the variable, or something else like that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found using the `preceding`/`preceding-sibling` axes in a `count()` can sometimes be slower than using something like `xsl:number` to do the counting.

Example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="idToCheck" select="'82'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/people">
    <xsl:variable name="positionOfPerson">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="person[@id=$idToCheck]" mode="pos"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$positionOfPerson"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="pos">
    <xsl:number/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*As so often happens, as I was typing up my question, I discovered the solution.  I thought I would post it here to aid anyone else who might encounter a similar problem.*</sup>

---

You just need to find the node that matches your id, and then use `preceding-sibling` to count all the nodes before it.  Add 1, and you have your position.

```
<xsl:variable name="positionOfPerson" select="count(/people/person[@id = $idToCheck]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1" />
<xsl:value-of select="$positionOfPerson" />
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as the accepted answer so people know that the question was answered. Personally I often look for unanswered questions and it is really annoying to notice that a question was answered after thinking a few minutes about a solution.

Comment: @RobertS.  Sorry about that.  I wanted to see if people had other solutions, and it turns out that in this case, [someone else did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45198711/3662867).  I've marked it as accepted now.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

Iterate recursively over the list until you find the element your searching.
Use a parameter for the position you're currently iterating over

```
<xsl:variable name="idToCheck" select="'82'" />
<xsl:variable name="position">
<xsl:call-tamplate name="getPos">
<xsl:with-param name="pList" select="insert-parent-node-selector"/>
<xsl:with-param name="pElement" select="insert-specific-person-node-selector"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template name="getPos">
<xsl:param name="pElement" select="."/>
<xsl:param name="pList"/>
<xsl:param name="pNumber">1</xsl:param>


<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="pElement = pList[1]">
<xsl:value-of slect="pNumber">
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:call-tamplate name="getPos">
<xsl:with-param name="pList" select="pList[position() > 1]"/>
<xsl:with-param name="pElement"pElement"/>
<xsl:with-param name="pNumber"pNumber + 1"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I don't think `<xsl:when test="pElement = pList[1]">` does what you think it does.

Comment: @michael.hor257k mhh could be, I don't know for sure if it also compares attributes that way. But that could be fixed really easy by picking the attribute id instead of the node it self. correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I am not talking about attributes vs. elements. I am talking about comparing string-values of nodes (which you are doing) vs. comparing nodes for identity (which I believe you think you are doing).

Comment: That's indeed what I thought I was doing. thanks for mentioning. /node() should fix that problem right?

Comment: No. You need to either compare the nodes' ids or test that their count returns 1.

Comment: or you could (a bit dirty) select them by the value of the result sets and compare the 2 nodes that way. But I like your solution of the count. that's really clever.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the value of the result sets".

Comment: Never mind, now I think of it again I see it won't work. Your solution with the count would be the neatest way to do it.